# Can i update firestore and storage of firebase in one line Code? using React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, shortcode

I am updating firestore and Storage of Firebase React.js .

```
import "firebase/compat/storage";
import firebase from "config.js";

const [image, setImage] = useState();

firebase
  .storage()
  .ref("images/" + image.name)
  .put(image)
  .then(({ ref }) => {
    ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      firebase.firestore().collection("images").doc().set({ imageURL: url });
    });
  });

return (
  <input
    type="file"
    name="profile"
    onChange={() => setImage(event.target.files[0])}
  />
);
```

can we write this code to any other way. I mean, can I remove the repeating `firebase.` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use below code.I have tried the below example which uploads an image and returns the downloadURL and stores it in a Firestore document.I have used Firebase modular sdk v9, You can try the code below. It is in typescript you may change it to javascript if required.

```
import { addDoc, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
import { useState } from "react";
import { db, storage } from "./config/firebase";

export default function App() {
  let downloadURL:string;
  const upload = async (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const selectedFiles = event.target.files as FileList;
    const dop = ref(storage, `${selectedFiles?.[0].name}`);
    const data = await uploadBytes(dop, selectedFiles?.[0]);
    downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(data.ref);
    console.log(downloadURL);
    const firestoreRef = collection(db, "images");
    const result = await addDoc(firestoreRef, {
      imageUrl: downloadURL
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
  return (
    <input
    type="file"
    name="profile"
    onChange={upload}
  />
  )
}
```

Also I can see you are using a deprecated version of Firebase Storage you can use the latest version which solves the multiple Firebase issues.

You can try using [React Firebase Hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase-hooks) which provides convenience listeners for files stored within Firebase Cloud Storage.